# Voice Unlock Problems on Android Lollipop(Lenovo A6000)

Tags: voice-recognition, voice-command, google-voice-actions

Recently,I had heard about the voice unlocking mechanism in Android,which lets us unlock our lock-screen using our voice.

As shown in the first screenshot, I have enabled all options:

[image: All options enabled] [image: Annoying "Listening..." Box] [image: Home screen appears after "Listening...." dialog]
<sup>Screenshots: Options enabled / Annoying Box / Homescreen afterwards (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Now,I lock my phone. I switch on the screen,and then say "OK Google".

But then this is what annoys me. I want the home screen to pop up as soon as I have said the command,but instead what comes up is what the second screenshot shows.

And then my home screen appears, after the "Listening..." Box, as shown in the third screenshot above.

I do NOT want the Google "Listening..." dialog to pop up.I only want the home screen to pop up as soon as I have said the command.

I HAVE done a lot of searching... but to no avail.

Can anyone solve this?

PS: My phone is a Lenovo A6000 with CyanogenMod 12.1.

Comment: Does disabling the first option affect the others?

Comment: Yes.When I disable the first option,the others are automatically disabled, can't enable them.Weird huh?